# Why does drush say "command not found" when I try to execute remote commands?

Tags: drush

When I use a drush command to do something on a remote machine, I get the following message:

> bash: drush: command not found

What's the problem?

Comment: The way I see your question, it is still about bash, not Drupal itself. Nor about drush, really, because if command isn't executed, it does not matter if it's drush, tree, wget or what. And I write it without seeing any answers, my opinion is based only on the question, just as you asked.

Comment: @Mołot: Once you know the answer (and only then) it might seem to be about bash, because you realize that the source of the problem is with bash, but before you know the answer, it looks like the message means "Bash is saying that Drush is saying that the command is not found".  Bash *appears* initially to only be carrying a message from Drush.  Of course that's not what is really happening, but you don't know that ***until you know the answer***.  The *question* therefore is a question that a Drupal user may have, about (as far as they know) Drush.  The *answer* brings Bash to the forefront.

Comment: **I haven't even seen there is any answer** when I posted my comment above. It is plain in your question that you are asking about bash unable to find command. You quote the error line where bash reports that it can't find drush. You, not any answerer. My first comment was in review queue and we don't even see answers there. We don't even see *if* there are any.

Comment: Not only does the syntax of colons seem to imply *Bash is saying that Drush is saying...*, but as far as the user is concerned, a *Drush* command was issued, so it's most natural to interpret the command that is being referred to as the Drush command, rather than Drush itself.

Comment: "Answer" = "solution".  "Answer != "reply".  You knew the solution before you read any replies.  That's not going to be true for everyone.  Questions must be categorized by the content of the *question* not the content of the *answer* (or "solution" if you prefer).

Comment: The fact that is plain to *you* that bash is complaining about not knowing where Drush is only proves my point that you see the solution.  Lots of people don't.  That's why sites like this exist.

Comment: Ask yourself this: what site would someone go to for an answer if they have this exact question?  (They would not go to a Bash-related site because they believe Drush is the source of the problem rather than the object of the problem.)

Comment: Though I think, the problem itself is definitely off-topic. Saying that it looks like "Drush complaining that it can't find the (sub)command you may be trying to give it", to me at least, comes across as having done too little research, as trying "drush tpt493a8y" will immediately show a completely different error. On the other hand, it's probably entirely correct that people will come here, as they will probably think it's drush related, the votes alone speak to that. However, I don't see that as a reason to open the question. We can have a perfectly good answer here, in a closed question.

Comment: continued: Leaving it closed clearly indicates that any follow up questions should go else where, such as SO, and no not here. Leaving the question open would encourage more shell related questions, which are likely off-topic. Additionally, the argument over the question does not belong in the question itself, and by reverting a mods edit you risk coming across as a trouble maker. I'd be careful with that.

Comment: "Leaving the question open would encourage more shell related questions, which are likely off-topic" that's a completely baseless claim.  People are coming here because they are using Drush and having a problem.  There's no way they're going to read this and then start thinking they should ask about shell quoting or `sed` commands here.  That would be absurd.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This message is from the remote machine complaining that it didn't understand where to find the `drush` executable, *not* Drush complaining that it can't find the (sub)command you may be trying to give it, even though the punctuation suggests the latter. (If `bash:` means Bash is  passing you a message, then `drush:` should mean the same thing--if there's any consistency. But actually it is intended to mean `drush:` is the subject of the message, not the source of the message passed through `bash:` to you.  It would be clearer if the second `:` were removed.)

Drush logs into your remote machine over ssh, but it's not a normal interactive login, so it doesn't source the .bash_profile.  It does, however, source the .bashrc file.

Add the drush path (not including drush itself, just including the directory containing drush) to the PATH variable in your remote .bashrc and all should be well.  For instance, that may look like this:

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/zend/bin
```

Comment: Also look out for the following in your ~/.bashrc: `[ -z "$PS1" ] && return`. Some platforms use this to bail out if running in non-interactive mode. Ubuntu, for example, puts this in your initial .bashrc.  If you set your PATH, you need to make sure that you set it before any conditional such as this one that may force an early exit.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and comment. I had to edit the path in `.bashrc` before the line 
`# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac` on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940533/how-do-i-set-path-such-that-ssh-userhost-command-works/941995#941995) may help if the above answer doesn't. On MacOS Catalina, I had to add a `zshenv` file (without a leading dot) with my desired export paths inside /etc (not my home directory).