# How do I use a drush alias to connect to a docker container?

Tags: 8, drush

I have a droplet setup on Digital Ocean with two docker containers, one for Drupal (using modified [alpine-drupal8](https://github.com/bytepark/alpine-drupal8) image) and another running a simple mysql server.

I am able to run drush commands on this container by connecting over ssh into the droplet and running `docker exec -it <container_name> /bin/sh`
I have also set up an ssh server (listening on port 2222 on the same ip address) on the container itself with a little port forwarding:

```
ssh root@<droplet_ip> -p 2222 # Connects from remote dev machine to drupal container using ssh key
```

My sites/default/drush/aliases.drushrc.php file:

```
<?php

$aliases['container'] = array(
  'root' => '/usr/share/nginx/html',
  'uri' => 'http://default',
  'path-aliases' =>
  array (
    '%drush' => '/usr/local/bin/drush',
    '%site' => 'sites/default/',
    '%files' =>'sites/default/files/',
    '%modules' =>'modules/'
  ),

  'remote-host' => '<droplet_ip>',
  'remote-user' => 'root',
  'ssh-options' => '-p 2222',
);

?>
```

Starting an ssh session with the drush alias is working:

```
$ drush @container ssh
186203cca:/usr/share/nginx/html# ### Connected to ssh session in droplet
186203cca:/usr/share/nginx/html# which drush
/usr/local/bin/drush
186203cca:/usr/share/nginx/html# drush status
 Drupal version                  :  8.1.8
 Site URI                        :  http://default
 Database driver                 :  mysql
 Database hostname               :  <removed>
 Database port                   :  <removed>
 Database username               :  <removed>
 Database name                   :  <removed>
 Drupal bootstrap                :  Successful
 Drupal user                     :
 Default theme                   :  <removed>
 Administration theme            :  seven
 PHP configuration               :  /etc/php7/php.ini
 PHP OS                          :  Linux
 Drush script                    :  /usr/local/bin/drush
 Drush version                   :  8.1.3
 Drush temp directory            :  /tmp
 Drush configuration             :
 Drush alias files               :
 Install profile                 :  standard
 Drupal root                     :  /usr/share/nginx/html
 Drupal Settings File            :  sites/default/settings.php
 Site path                       :  sites/default
 File directory path             :  sites/default/files
 Temporary file directory path   :  /tmp
 Sync config path                :  sites/default/files/config_vxs7qxuAqrfCtOXdbGYLvLAIKl1_bN4J_BvmrEn1l1EUIsn4Du_CKck2QWYSmkNDgUVfdZUZVQ/sync
```

However, I still can't seem to run actual drush commands:

```
$ drush @container status
env: can't execute 'drush': No such file or directory
```

My theory is that the port forwarding is not working correctly, and drush is trying to run on the container, not the droplet

This may be related to my issue: [Why does drush say "command not found" when I try to execute remote commands?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/45913/why-does-drush-say-command-not-found-when-i-try-to-execute-remote-commands)

---

Update:

A little more testing and I found out I can use drupal console without issues, so it seems this is isolated to drush only:

```
$ drupal @container cr all

 Rebuilding cache(s), wait a moment please.


 [OK] Done clearing cache(s).
```

Comment: Post your drush alias configuration for the site without any credential or connection information.

Comment: I've made some progress and updated the question.

Comment: Why u don't just enter your docker container with -> https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/

Comment: I can enter the container as you describe, or use ssh directly. The problem is that none of the drush alias commands are working

Comment: The example at https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/blob/master/examples/example.aliases.drushrc.php says that the %drush option "points to the folder that the drush script is stored in." but you have set it to the executable.

Answer (score 2):

So this one threw me for a while this evening as well.

Here's what ended working:

```
$aliases['docker'] = array(
  'uri' => 'http://localhost:8080',
  'php' => '/usr/bin/php',
  'root' => '/var/www',
  'remote-user' => 'root',
  'remote-host' => '0.0.0.0',
  'ssh-options' => '-p 8022 -o PasswordAuthentication=no -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa',
  'path-aliases' =>
  array (
    '%drush' => '/root/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/drush'
  )
);
```

The remote host of 0.0.0.0 ended up doing the trick. Seems that if you use localhost or 127.0.0.1 drush doesn't actually try to ssh in.